# Let the user pick a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to create a Windows form that lets the user choose a SQL Server instance to connect to and run a query on that database that should be there.

Is this possible? How do I create a dynamic SQL connection?

Comment: There is this class [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

To create a connection string you can use [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx), after that you can pass created connection string into [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    UserID = "Some User ID",
    Password = "Some Database Password",
    InitialCatalog = "Some Initial Catalog",
    DataSource = "Some Data Source"
};

string connectionString = builder.ToString();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //...
}
```